# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException issue in Android Studio 4.1.1 , after creating new project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

After updating android studio 4.1.1 , getting errors when creating new project as

```
Could not get unknown property 'com' for root project 'MyApp' of type org.gradle.api.Project.` `* Exception is:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'com' for root project 'MyApp' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.getProperty(ConfigureDelegate.java:130)
    at sync_studio_tooling2_5pg2usyhi86d5n101u1apwwoh$_run_closure1.doCall
```

`

Comment: When creating a new project or after creating it?

Comment: After creating new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue when added lower version in **gradle-wrapper.properties** like `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip` instead of `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip`